# GAD67 Effect on Sleep

Tags: sleep

Glutamate decarboxylase enzyme converts Glutamate into GABA.

Also increase in gaba levels decrease gad activity!

why does increased gaba levels decrease GAD activity?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! You are invited to take the [tour](https://health.stackexchange.com/tour). Please also read the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help) and especially the section about asking here. If you [edit](https://health.stackexchange.com/posts/14286/edit) your question to include definitions for your abbreviations and perhaps a bit on your prior research you will improve the quality of your question and increase the chances of getting a good answer.